# Magento 2: The value of attribute "is_new" must be set

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.1

Whenever I try to save a category I get **The value of attribute "is_new" must be set**. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is setting 'empty' default value - ' '. Then there is no exception, but this default value as empty is set in db.

Should be treated as bug in my opinion - [github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7232)

Answer (score 0):

**The value of attribute "is_new" must be set.** to resolve this error remove required option from database . 
Go to your database in **phpmyadmin** and select **eav_attribute** table . 
Search "is_new" in this table and set   is_required to 0(zero). then try to add new category .

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:
Magento 2.2.3

Go to table "eav_attribute":
find line attribute code "is new" and edit:

1. mark "is required" to: 0
2. under "default value" text, uncheck the check box and set (write in) the field box: 0

Must work